# Cannot connect to webcam with opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I was working on my project and suddenly I found out I can't connect my webcam anymore! The thing is, it was working fine in windows x64, but when I changed the project to x32 it started having problems. When I run the code, it behaves completely random! 70% of the time it goes to the `capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);` command but it will never come out of that command, 25% of the time it finishes the command but capture still remains 0, and 5% of the time it works fine (sometimes when I restart the windows). I'm sure the webcam is connected correctly because I can see the webcam from movie maker and see the webcam getting video just fine (I close movie maker before I run the program, so nothing else is connected to it!)

I have this simple code but as I said, it isn't working correctly in line 2. What is causing this problem? Note: opencv version 2.4.2 is being used.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    Sleep(1000);
    int q; 
    cin>>q;
    if(!capture)
    {
        printf("Could not initialize capturing...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    IplImage* frame = 0;
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    cvShowImage("video", frame);
    int c = cvWaitKey(20);

     cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: means it doesen't give any error but after running line 2 , capture stays 0 and doesen't change.

Comment: Did your camera open?

Comment: you should use the c++ api. you are using the old deprecated api.

Comment: and then, how have you installed opencv?

Comment: By opencv no cause capture remains 0 but with movie maker yes It opens

Comment: I didn't get the c++ api part but the install part I downloaded it from opencvs official site and run the setup , what can be wrong with the installation.

Comment: I found out the newest version of opencv has this error and if someone got the error that I'm having now you can downgrade to make the capture work